# Running 2 Separate Containers Apache-PHP and PHP-FPM

Tags: php, apache, fpm

I've been circling around if it is proper to have this setup

```
Container1 = Running with Apache + PHP
Container2 = Running with PHP-FPM with index.php (running phpinfo page) on /var/www/html
```

Then Container1 will have a configuration to forward request to Container2 for fast cgi.
Will that be possible? I already did a lot of retries found from online and I for me to view the phpinfo page is I need to place it both of the /var/www/html of container1 and container2.

Comment: Container 1 doesn't need PHP at all, it just forwards FastCGI requests to Container 2.

Comment: Not sure of that, I think Container 1 needs php support and php modules to make sure it can communicate to php-fpm

Comment: _[taps original comment]_